# How to copy and paste an existing .xlm workbook file ona certain date and time without opening the existing file?

Tags: excel, vba

How to copy and paste an existing .xlm workbook file automatically on a certain date and time without opening the existing file?

I have a vba workbook file which I use to record certain data monthly. At the end of the month I must save this workbook and start a new workbook file by copying the existing file and thereafter I manually revise certain data ( such as dates, names, figures etc.)before I start using it again to record my usual daily data. 
I would like to have copy-paste-revise actions automatically at a certain date and time: for example 1st of the new month at 07:00 AM.
I will appreciate any suggestions on how to go about it?
Thanks
SATAMAN

Comment: Consider creating an event procedure that runs when you open the workbook. This procedure checks whether it was run at any time after 7 AM in the previous month. If not, it will make the changes you mention. Once these changes are in place the code will not run again until 7 AM on the first day of the next month. This method avoids running a procedure OnTime which is liable to cause more trouble than it gives benefit.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion; I will try and inform you the outcome in a few days' time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic structure of code which will run not **at** a specific time but **after** it. In fact, it runs whenever the workbook is opened but takes no action until a certain date has passed. This is an event procedure. It must be copied to the *ThisWorkbook* code module. It's designed for testing and tested. Run it on a blank worksheet with a date in A1.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ' "TestCell" is the cell in your worksheet that contains
    ' a date that is updated to the current month when this program runs
    Const TestCell As String = "A1"
    Dim TestRng As Range
    Dim Test As Variant

    ' "Sheet1" is the CodeName of the "Monthly Data" tab
    ' it remains the same whichever tab name the user gives.
    ' Change the CodeName in the Properties window.
    With Sheet1
        Set TestRng = .Range(TestCell)
        Test = TestRng.Value
        If IsDate(Test) Then                        ' skip if no date
            If Month(Test) < Month(Date) Then       ' skip if date is in this month
                ' this presumes that you will want the same action
                ' even if Test is more than a month ago.
                ' If not, you can separate ways at this point.

                With ThisWorkbook
                    ' This command creates a copy of this workbook under
                    ' any name in any location while keeping ThisWorkbook
                    ' open and in its original location.
                    ' This means that the current workbook always retains
                    ' its name and copies are renamed to reflect the period
                    ' they cover. You might also strip copies of their code
                    ' by changing the file format.
                    ' You might adapt your naming conventions to such a system.
                    .SaveCopyAs Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\" & .Name
                    FormatWorkbookForNewMonth CDate(Test), TestRng
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub FormatWorkbookForNewMonth(ByVal LastDate As Date, _
                                      TestRng As Range)

    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    Set Ws = TestRng.Worksheet

    ' do the changes to the workbook here

    TestRng.Value = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
End Sub
```

You should have one cell on your worksheet on which other dates, such as dates in captions, in your worksheet are based. Once this date changes the meaning of the sheet changes with it. Such a cell is ideal for identifying whether a change has taken place and even what that change was. In the code above I have designated A1 - easy to change in the code. The event procedure simply checks if the date is in a previous month and jumps into action when it isn't.

The present procedure creates a copy of the file (on your desktop for now) and resets the date in A1 to the first day of the current month. So, if the same procedure is run again no action will be taken until the month changes.

BTW, although this is an event procedure which is triggered by the *Open* event, you can actually run it on F5 as well.

Comment: Thank You for the code and advise on how to code and run a work book_open macro on a specific time.  I used your suggestions and sample code with a test code and it worked fine on the 1st April 2020. I also tried on my original project and it worked  fine as well adding

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way in VBA to schedule a Macro for a specific date. You can use Application.OnTime to trigger a macro at specifed time.

You can either create an Exe and add it to Windows scheduler or Check for date in your macro and call the macro by resetting Application.OnTime.

```
Sub MyProc()
If Day(Now) = 1 Then

    ' Execute the proc
End If
' extend procedure schedule by a day
 Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("24:00:00"), "MyProc"
End Sub
```

src: https://p2p.wrox.com/excel-vba/72435-schedule-excel-run-macro-specific-time-date.html#post233865

Comment: Dear Mech. Thank you for your advice and src link. I will try and come back to you soonest.

Comment: Please select an answer to help users with the same issue find the solution.